# Is there a better way to say 'feel free to get back to me later'?

Tags: email

I'm writing an email to ask my friend some questions, it's on the weekend so I just want to be polite and let him know it's okay to get back to me later. Is there a way I can express this meaning while not being so formal? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question actually, since this is quite a common requirement when talking to friends, I have found.

- No need to write back straight away!
- No rush to respond!
- Take your time, no need to respond straight away!
- You don't need to get back to me straight away!

And so on.

Comment: Hello, legatrix. Please look at the advice given at the Help Center. 'A better way to phrase' questions are writing advice, off-topic on ELU.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - That may be as strictly stated. I think of these as questions about common usage and meaning. Better than "Which of these answers is best for my test".

Comment: @Elliot They are almost always answered by lists of paraphrases, the best of which to select being largely opinion rather than the evidenced definitive answer (or at least an approach) desired on ELU.